# Boost with CMakeLists on Visual Studio

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, boost, cmake

I'm trying to run some code with boost, but i can't include any boost file, like "boost/timer/timer.hpp". My CMakeLists contains

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(Converter)

find_package(Boost)
include_directories(${BOOST_INCLUDE_DIRS})
LINK_DIRECTORIES(${Boost_LIBRARIES})
add_executable(Converter converter.cpp)

TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(Converter  ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
message("boost lib: ${Boost_LIBRARY_DIRS}, inc: ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR}")
```

[CMake answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sy4jk.png)

My cpp file contains

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/timer/timer.hpp>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << "Hello world!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

And when i am trying to build it, there is a error: "Cannot open include file 'boost/timer/timer.hpp'"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a wrong non existing variable here. To set the include Boost directories to your project you need to use `Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS`, the case of the variable matters. And your link directories should be set to `Boost_LIBRARY_DIRS`.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(Converter)

find_package(Boost COMPONENTS timer)
include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories(${Boost_LIBRARY_DIRS})
add_executable(Converter converter.cpp)

target_link_libraries(Converter PUBLIC ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
message("boost lib: ${Boost_LIBRARY_DIRS}, inc: ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR}")
```

Your small project can be further simplified by using the imported targets `Boost::headers` as follows:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(Converter)

find_package(Boost COMPONENTS timer REQUIRED)
add_executable(Converter converter.cpp)

target_link_libraries(Converter PUBLIC Boost::headers Boost::timer)
message("boost lib: ${Boost_LIBRARY_DIRS}, inc: ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS}")
```

Comment: there is another problem **LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'libboost_timer-vc141-mt-gd-x64-1_66.lib'**. Is this related to installation error of boost? @vre

Comment: @ArmenGevorkian you need to add `COMPONENTS` to `find_package`: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindBoost.html

Comment: @ArmenGevorkian Added the timer library to Boost components.

Comment: nah, doesn't work clean:( @vre _CMake Error at C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/CMake/CMake/share/cmake-3.20/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:230 (message):
  Could NOT find Boost (missing: timer) (found version "1.66.0")_

Comment: That likely means your compiled boost does not have this library. Are you mixing 32 and 64 bit? No longer using Visual Studio 2017?

Comment: @ArmenGevorkian Did you build Boost lib yourself or downloaded [prebuilt binaries](https://sourceforge.net/projects/boost/files/boost-binaries/) for your compiler? To further debug the issue add `set(Boost_DEBUG ON)` to your CMakeLists.txt before the find_package command.